# "Come while feeling" vs "come by feeling"

Tags: prepositions

> I study English **'listening**' to music.

It means that I learn English by setting what I learn to song, listening and sing it. So it is 'by listening' not 'while listening' that is omitted

Here's another sentence written in my book.

> A vacation can make you more productive because you come back **'feeling'** more motivated and ready to work harder.

Then, how about this? which is omitted of 'by' and 'while'? If I need to mean 'while', is it not possible to omit 'while' because it can mean 'by' not 'while'?

Answer (score 1):

For the first, you should say "I study English by listening to music".

For the second, you should insert "back" before "feeling".

Although "while" can include "by" in the first sentence, you can only ignore the two different meanings if you are concentrating on the aspect of listening that doesn't care about the ambiguity. So you might write, "Since I study English while listening to music, I was very unhappy when my CD player broke". In this case, it doesn't matter whether you study with music in the background or by paying attention to it. With the CD player (or MP3 player, or speaker, or earbuds) broken, you can do neither.

Answer (score 0):

How do we know whether the **-ing** form refers to *concurrent time* ("while") or to *state* (adjective)?

study {something} [while] listening to ....

return from vacation feeling refreshed [adjective]

The underlying verb of the -ing form (e.g. listen, feel) may require a complement. Once you have that complement (listening *to music*....feeling *refreshed*) you can make sense of the statement.

We don't understand language at the semantic level one word at a time. We take statements in by phrases.